# How to model Companies and Persons in a Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I am new to Rails and I am trying to build an application where one **User** can have many **Organisations** which can have many **Persons** which in turn can have many **Projects**.

These are my models (does it make sense at all?):

Users ---< Companies ---< Persons ---< Projects

Now my key question is what will happen if a person does not belong to any company at all? Will my application still work and will I still be able to access projects, for example like this...

```
current_user.persons.projects
```

...despite there being no company?

There is probably a fairly simple way to model these tables in Rails, but for some reason I just can't get my head around this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With associations you can set up a structure, as posted in the answer by ge0man.

With [validations](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Validations) you can make sure the model has the right properties required before saving / updating.

If you dont and you call a function like User.projects it will just return an empty array, because no project listed to that user were found :)

Comment: OK, thanks. Actually I am already using validations extensively. I was just wondering if my model setup will work in general.

Comment: if you require a user: `validate_presence_of :user_id` in the company model. If you don't validate the presence and call @company.user it will either return the User object or nil if its not set. Other way around if you call @company.user.companies it will return all companies the user of the current company is linked to. (It generates `SELECT * FROM companies WHERE user_id = {user.id}` in the background)

Answer (score 1):

Person and Organization is not a hierarchical relationship. It seems like one, but it isn't. It's a graph.

An organization can have 0+ sub-organizations. It can have 0+ employees over time, and a person can work for more than one organization at the same time.

You can also sell to, or purchase from an individual or an organization, so you must model them as the same super-type.

This is called the Party model and I would suggest reading up on it here before you start.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into using the

belongs_to and has_many in your models.

Check out this guide below.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

> Now my key question is what will happen if a person does not belong to
>   any company at all? Will my application still work and will I still be
>   able to access projects, for example like this...

Answer to your key question is: yes, any user will be able to access projects that belong to people with no company thus:

```
Project.all
```